# how to add an image to user playing activity?(discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

Iam trying to add image user activity status in discord.py and basically, the problem is that I can't seem to add an image so I looked up discord.py API but couldn't find how to do it. So if you know do answer.

Would like to know how to add one. (**NOT FOR BOTS**)

**Here is the code**

```
import discord, os, keep_alive, datetime
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import tasks


intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client()

launch_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Account Activated")
  print(launch_time)
  if not Status_loop.is_running():
     Status_loop.start()
```

**Put it in a loop to constantly update the activity**

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1, count=None, reconnect=True)
async def Status_loop():
  delta_uptime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - launch_time
  hours, remainder = divmod(int(delta_uptime.total_seconds()), 3600)
  minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
  days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
  print(f"Online Time: {days:02d}d | {hours:02d}h | {minutes:02d}m | {seconds:02d}s")
  await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.dnd,
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, 
    large_image = "https://i.imgur.com/Kk2BvJg.jpg",
    large_text = "This is Game Icon",
    name = "Sleeping Simulator",
    details = "Dreams of Desires(Easy)",
    state = f"{days:02d}d | {hours:02d}h | {minutes:02d}m Passed"))
```

**Here is the Status on a user account**

[image]

If you are wondering why I am even doing this, well I just wanted a custom status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after trying sites and other kinds of ways to do it, I finally got it using replit uploaded file link... and it worked...

```
    large_image = "https://e8a593e1-79cc-4f08-9992-2b588af90e7f.id.repl.co/static/sleepingface.jpg",
    large_text = "This is Game Icon",
    small_image = "https://e8a593e1-79cc-4f08-9992-2b588af90e7f.id.repl.co/static/sleepingface.jpg",
    small_text = "This is Game Icon",
```

The result:

[image]